# No internet access in most applications

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, malware

My friend is struggling with getting internet access on his Windows 10 computer, my guess is that some type of malware is interfering with his network settings, but I haven't been able to find anything suspect aside from sketchy root certificates.

Before you ask, yes we have tried scanning for malware using various anti-malware tools, and no threats have turned up. He says he has done so in the past and removed any threats, so I'm confident that the malware is gone and that we're dealing with remnants.

Symptoms are as follows; Chrome, IE, Spotify, Steam, Discord and a slew of games and utilities have no internet access what so ever. Some simply crash on launch, others show actual errors. Not even our routers config page or other LAN devices are accessible from the browsers.

I can `ping` local devices and remote websites no problem, with their domain names and IP addresses alike. `nslookup` also works as expected, always showing correct information. According to `nslookup` it is using our router's default settings.

System proxy and DNS settings appear untouched, but I tried with Google's DNS for good measure which didn't change a thing, still no access for applications but commandline was a-okay. Also ran `wget` from PowerShell which worked fine. I installed Firefox, which also worked fine.

I tried uninstalling Chrome and removing all settings from `%appdata%`, but when running the setup tool it complains about no internet access, and I'm guessing the same is true for every other previously installed application. We also tried wifi hotspots, no luck.

We disabled the firewall, tried booting in safe-mode with networking, yet still no applications have internet... So I really have no idea how to proceed at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"...yes we have tried scanning for malware using various anti-malware tools, and no threats have turned up. He says he has done so in the past and removed any threats, so I'm confident that the malware is gone and that we're dealing with remnants."*  Please take the time to read this previous question.  Realistically, if you have previously encountered malware on that machine the only way to completely have peace of mind is to reload Windows: http://superuser.com/q/100360/650163

Comment: So (Chrome,IE,Spotify,Steam, and Discord) all use the operating system's certificate store.  Firefox uses its own certificate store.  So the fact, "I installed Firefox, which also worked fine.", indicates a certificate problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue before. Unfortunately, reloading Windows is the only fix I found.

It has something to do with certificates I believe, the malware blocks a port (or series of ports) and certificates/data don't get through, but other things do which confuses the user.

This is from memory since I don't remember the exact error, but googling the error that came up on chrome when trying to load a webpage (on another machine) brought me to a page explaining it.

Comment: "and certificates/data don't get through" - This isn't how SSL/TLS certificates work.

Comment: You're right, I vaguely remember this issue. Either way, the fix is to do a clean install

Comment: Seems a little extreme for a problem that could easily be diagnosed with a couple key details.